# Issues running unit test cases on selenium grid 2 using Intern test framework

Tags: javascript, testing, intern

I am trying to run unit test cases on Selenium grid 2 using intern. Is it even supported?

Here is my config file:

```
{
  environments: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: [
                    'disable-restore-session-state',
                    'disable-web-security',
                    'no-sandbox'
                ]
            }
        }
    ],

    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:dist|node_modules|tests)\//,

    loader: {
        map: {
            '*': {
                bundler: 'xxxBundle',
                'conf.json': 'dist/conf.json'
            }
        },
        packages: [
            {
                name: 'dojo',
                location: 'node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo'
            },
            {
                name: 'sinon',
                location: 'node_modules/sinon',
                main: 'pkg/sinon.js'
            }
        ],
        paths: clientPaths
    },

    reporters: reporters,
    functionalSuites: [ ],
    suites: [
        'tests/unit/app/application'
    ],

    useSauceConnect: false,
    proxyPort: 9000,
    proxyUrl: 'drivexgridmaster.xxx.com:9000/',

    tunnel: 'NullTunnel',

    tunnelOptions: {
        host: 'drivexgridmaster.xxx.com:4444',
        port: '4444'
    },

    webdriver: {
        host: 'drivexgridmaster.xxx.com',
        port: 4444
    },

    useLoader: {
        'host-browser': hostBrowser
    }
};
```

I am getting the following error:

Error:This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The URL on the browser is :
http://xxx:9000/__intern/client.html?config=tests%2Funit-client-config-grid&reporters=webdriver&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fapp%2Fapplication&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fapp%2Fcommon%2FcommonUtil&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-general%2Fcontroller&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-general%2Fviews%2Findex&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-items-rules%2Fcontroller&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-items-rules%2Fviews%2Fcondition&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-items-rules%2Fviews%2Findex&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-items-rules%2Fviews%2Frule&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-items%2Fcontroller&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail-items%2Fviews%2Findex&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-detail%2Fviews%2Findex&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-layout%2Fcontroller&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-layout%2Fviews%2Findex&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-master%2Fcontroller&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-master%2Fviews%2Findex&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fcomponents%2Fnode-search%2Fviews%2Findex&suites=tests%2Funit%2Fmodels%2Fnode%2Fmodel&baseUrl=%2F&sessionId=9e1d6fc6-2bd1-411f-bf3c-15fbd7a1b7b2